# Unknown website using my domain name

Tags: dns, domain

I own andchat.net which I've left dormant and should not lead to any website. My nameservers were pointing to ns1.linode.com and ns2.linode.com (my previous hosts).

Today I just realized if I visit the domain it leads to an actual website! How is this possible?

(From domaintools whois: Website Title    duckSpike.net - irc.duckspike.net )
This site is hosted with OVH in Canada.

When I left Linode a few years ago I deleted my account using their tool. I've now changed the nameserver to the Moniker default.

Comment: I don't think this is a security issue at all. How do you "own" the domain?

Answer (score 1):

Most-likely, when you cancelled your account, the domain was no longer associated with your account, and became 'up-for-grabs'. At this point, another user of this name server could claim this domain as their own, associating it with their account, and since it was still pointed at the same name servers, it works.

Serverfault has a question on this that goes into more detail [Can someone using the same DNS server as me hijack my domains?](https://serverfault.com/questions/744147/can-someone-using-the-same-dns-server-as-me-hijack-my-domains).

> I've now changed the nameserver to the Moniker default.

In that case, the squatters will lose it soon.